# What proof of identity documents do I need to apply for an Australian Passport in Australia?

Tags: passports, australia, uk-citizens, australian-citizens

I am an Australian Citizen (also British Citizen, born in the UK) and I am moving back to Australia from the UK. I want to apply for an Australian Passport when I get there. I have my Australian Citizenship Certificate.

Can I just apply at the post office in Australia using the applicable new passport application form ? My Aussie passport expired many years ago, but I have my British Passport, UK Driving Licence, national insurance number and European Health Card as proof of identity.

Will these documents suffice when I apply at the Post Office in Australia ?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. When asking a question anywhere on StackExchange, it is best to demonstrate some initial research effort; for example, have you consulted the [Apply for a passport](https://ppol.passports.gov.au/web/forms/entrypoint.aspx) page on the Australian Passport Office's website? I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.

Comment: You may want to apply for your passport *before* you move to Australia.  You wouldn't want any trouble at the border.  Australia seems [not to require](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Citi/Curr/Dual-citizenship) that its citizens use Australian passports to enter, but they do recommend it.  Also, the [documentary requirements](https://www.passports.gov.au/passportsexplained/theapplicationprocess/eligibilityoverview/Pages/confirmingidentity.aspx) for in-country applications may be harder for you to meet.  For example, you can't use your UK license for proof of ID unless you are outside Australia.

Comment: I have been on the gov.au site & looked at the passports section. The documents required fall into 3 categories, for Applications in Australia & Overseas Applications. Just a bit confusing, as I will be applying in Australia, but don't have the documents required. I do have the documents required for an overseas applicant, but would rather do it in Australia. I don't fancy a trip to the embassy in London for a process that may only take 15 mins or more. I went to Australia in June this year and also 2014 & had no problem getting in on my british passport. Cheers choster and phoog. Thanks.

Comment: "had no problem getting in on my british passport": Did you tell them you were Australian, and did they accept it? If so you may be fine, but getting in for a visit is not the same as getting in for a permanent move.  Did you have an ETA with your UK passport?

Comment: CLosing as unclear until the OP returns to clarify @phoog's query